# How to change the height on inline css by jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a div in my file and I am trying to change the height of the div element from jquery but nothing is working.

```
<div id="colorbox" class="" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" style="display: block; width: 820px; height: 459px; visibility: visible; top: 122px; left: 420px; position: absolute; opacity: 1;">
```

This is what I did:

```
 $('#colorbox').css({'width' : '100px', 'height' : '50px'});
```

This doesn't work.

I also tried this.

```
$("#colorbox").removeAttr('style').css("height","100px");
```

Comment: Your code should work fine, assuming it's within $(document).ready():  https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Try ** !important** after your height https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Comment: I just did a test and I added a class and that works.  `$("#colorbox").addClass ('colorbox_set');`

Comment: `$('#colorbox').css('height','200px !important');` doesn't work as well.

Comment: Is `#colorbox` div created dynamically e.g onclick or Ajax call or..?

Comment: Please define what is not working ? Your code sets the height value correctly but you also have 'top' defined that would position the element 122px below the screen. Check this : https://jsfiddle.net/4sxz3xL3/

Comment: Could there be another CSS rule somewhere in your files that applies to that div element?

Comment: It was being overridden by some other js. I found the issue now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the height using jQuery's built in function for height.

```
$("#colorbox").height(100);
```